# Can't download MinGW from Sourceforge

Tags: mingw, sourceforge

I wanted download MinGW C and C++ gnu compiler from  Sourceforge using mingw-get-inst-20120421.exe. It gives me an option to download pre-packaged repository or latest one. When I am behind Kaspersky AV firewall latest one fails. Pre- one fails in any case. In any case  they don't install gcc.exe at all. This is the image of my mingw/bin directory:

http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/5953/capturephw.jpg

```
    mingw-get.exe: *** WARNING *** http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/pkginfo-0.5-mingw32-beta-20120416-1-bin.tar.xz?download: opened with unexpected status: code = 404
mingw-get.exe: *** WARNING *** please report this to the mingw-get maintainer
mingw-get.exe: *** ERROR *** Get package: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/pkginfo-0.5-mingw32-beta-20120416-1-bin.tar.xz?download: download failed
install: mingw-get-0.5-mingw32-beta-20120416-1-bin.tar.xz
mingw-get.exe: *** ERROR *** required package file is not available
mingw-get.exe: *** ERROR *** cannot install mingw-get-0.5-mingw32-beta-20120416-1-bin.tar.xz
mingw-get.exe: *** ERROR *** due to previous download failure
install: mingw-get-0.5-mingw32-beta-20120416-1-lic.tar.xz
mingw-get.exe: *** ERROR *** required package file is not available
mingw-get.exe: *** ERROR *** cannot install mingw-get-0.5-mingw32-beta-20120416-1-lic.tar.xz
mingw-get.exe: *** ERROR *** due to previous download failure
install: pkginfo-0.5-mingw32-beta-20120416-1-bin.tar.xz
mingw-get.exe: *** ERROR *** required package file is not available
mingw-get.exe: *** ERROR *** cannot install pkginfo-0.5-mingw32-beta-20120416-1-bin.tar.xz
mingw-get.exe: *** ERROR *** due to previous download failure
install: libiconv-1.14-2-mingw32-dll-2.tar.lzma
 installing libiconv-1.14-2-mingw32-dll-2.tar.lzma
install: libgmp-5.0.1-1-mingw32-dll-10.tar.lzma
 installing libgmp-5.0.1-1-mingw32-dll-10.tar.lzma
install: libmpfr-2.4.1-1-mingw32-dll-1.tar.lzma
 installing libmpfr-2.4.1-1-mingw32-dll-1.tar.lzma
install: libpthreadgc-2.9.0-mingw32-pre-20110507-2-dll-2.tar.lzma
 installing libpthreadgc-2.9.0-mingw32-pre-20110507-2-dll-2.tar.lzma
install: pthreads-w32-2.9.0-mingw32-pre-20110507-2-dev.tar.lzma
 installing pthreads-w32-2.9.0-mingw32-pre-20110507-2-dev.tar.lzma
install: libquadmath-4.6.2-1-mingw32-dll-0.tar.lzma
 installing libquadmath-4.6.2-1-mingw32-dll-0.tar.lzma
install: libgomp-4.6.2-1-mingw32-dll-1.tar.lzma
 installing libgomp-4.6.2-1-mingw32-dll-1.tar.lzma
install: libmpc-0.8.1-1-mingw32-dll-2.tar.lzma
 installing libmpc-0.8.1-1-mingw32-dll-2.tar.lzma
install: libssp-4.6.2-1-mingw32-dll-0.tar.lzma
 installing libssp-4.6.2-1-mingw32-dll-0.tar.lzma
install: libgcc-4.6.2-1-mingw32-dll-1.tar.lzma
 installing libgcc-4.6.2-1-mingw32-dll-1.tar.lzma
install: libintl-0.18.1.1-2-mingw32-dll-8.tar.lzma
 installing libintl-0.18.1.1-2-mingw32-dll-8.tar.lzma
install: mingwrt-3.20-mingw32-dll.tar.gz
 installing mingwrt-3.20-mingw32-dll.tar.gz
install: w32api-3.17-2-mingw32-dev.tar.lzma
 installing w32api-3.17-2-mingw32-dev.tar.lzma
install: mingwrt-3.20-mingw32-dev.tar.gz
 installing mingwrt-3.20-mingw32-dev.tar.gz
install: binutils-2.22-1-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma
 installing binutils-2.22-1-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma
install: libexpat-2.0.1-1-mingw32-dll-1.tar.gz
 installing libexpat-2.0.1-1-mingw32-dll-1.tar.gz
install: gdb-7.4-2-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma
 installing gdb-7.4-2-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma
install: make-3.82-5-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma
 installing make-3.82-5-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma
install: gcc-4.6.2-1-mingw32-lic.tar.lzma
 installing gcc-4.6.2-1-mingw32-lic.tar.lzma
install: libstdc++-4.6.2-1-mingw32-dll-6.tar.lzma
 installing libstdc++-4.6.2-1-mingw32-dll-6.tar.lzma
install: gcc-core-4.6.2-1-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma
 installing gcc-core-4.6.2-1-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma
install: mingw32-base-2011060500-mingw32-bin.meta
 installing mingw32-base-2011060500-mingw32-bin.meta
install: gcc-4.6.2-1-mingw32-doc.tar.lzma
 installing gcc-4.6.2-1-mingw32-doc.tar.lzma
install: gcc-4.6.2-1-mingw32-lang.tar.lzma
 installing gcc-4.6.2-1-mingw32-lang.tar.lzma
install: gcc-c++-4.6.2-1-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma
 installing gcc-c++-4.6.2-1-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma
```

Answer (score 3):

The prdownloads.sourceforge.net URL often does not work.

My solution was to edit the file in at `var\lib\mingw-get\data\profile.xml` and change the `<repository uri="...>` line to:

```
<repository uri="http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get/catalogue/%F.xml.lzma/download">
```

Comment: Thank you so much this helped me

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3524614&group_id=2435&atid=202435) issue thread this may be an issue of a SourceForge. I've tried to install mingw using mingw-get today and the problem still exists.

Comment: Seems like it is OK now. I successfuly installed MinGW from SourceForge.

Comment: But it's not working today :( There are 1190 lines of: Update catalogue: package-list.xml
mingw-get.exe: *** ERROR *** http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/package-list.xml.lzma?download:cannot open URL
mingw-get.exe: *** ERROR *** Sync Repository: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/package-list.xml.lzma?download: download failed

Comment: Solved by **running mingw-get as admin and turning off DEP!**

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when trying to install MinGW on an AWS Windows instance with the GUI and CLI installer. I tried the above "repository uri" setting but that didn't help me.

It ended up being Internet Explorer's "Enhanced" security. Once I added https://*.sourceforge.net to my trusted sites it worked.

Comment: [Here](https://pryor.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001812843-Adding-sites-to-your-Trusted-Sites-List) is how to add `https://*.sourceforge.net` to your trusted sites.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it from osdn.net 
Here's the link: https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/releases/ 
It's same as sourceforge but was able to connect and download 
worked for me and my friends!

Answer (score 0):

run the minGW setup as administrator, this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense to me but changing the network worked for me. Try deleting mingw folder if you already have, and install again using a different network