# Cannot download and install some MinGw packages using installer

Tags: c++, windows-installer, mingw, sourceforge

**I'm unable to install 3 of the MinGw Packages using the get-installer. It shows that the installation has failed because it can't download the compressed file from the sourceforge site.** 
I need the MinGw packages for use in Code Blocks. Is there any way I can fix this issue (or) if possible

Can I download the remaining files manually?
Please chip in with a suggestion/method to help with completing the installation. I'm using a Windows 7 32-bit system.
[image: List of the packages I have already installed (in light green)]

[image: Installation failed message]

[image: My Window when faced with the error]

Comment: Error 12029 is a connection failure. `ERROR_INTERNET_CANNOT_CONNECT` Perhaps the site you're trying to install from is down. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/193625/info-wininet-error-codes-12001-through-12156

Comment: Thanks for letting me know what the error was! Is there a way to download the remaining packages manually?

Comment: As in, independently without the installer (from another server/link/mirror)?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342791/cant-download-mingw-from-sourceforge

Comment: Can you send me the discussion strings, it would be very helpful if you could...

Comment: Thank You! I'll check it out...

Comment: I don't know if you can download and install the packages manually. Looking at the mingw site on SourceForge it appears that maybe they have moved things and you might need a new installer to get the files if they are hosted in a different location.

Comment: I tried the latest installer but still, remaining packages don't seem to install...